# C# DataSet saving XML with CDATA

Tags: c#, xml, dataset

I have an XML Schema (xsd) and an XML data file that I read into a DataSet, bind to UI controls, then save the changes back to XML.

Within the XML I use CDATA since the XML data holds HTML strings.
However, when I save back to XML, the CDATA section is removed and
the "<" ">" are encoded, and I need to prevent this from happening.

For example I have this tag and data in my XML file:

```
<MyTag><![CDATA[My html string in <b>BOLD</b>]]></MyTag>
```

However when it is written out from DataSet.WriteXML() I initially got this:

```
<MyTag>My html string in &lt;b&gt;BOLD&lt;/b&gt;</MyTag>
```

Note that 1) CDATA is missing and 2) the "<" and ">" are encoded...

So I changed my code to alter the DataSet value prior to saving:

```
MyDataSet.Tables[0].Rows[0][0] = "<![CDATA[" + MyDataSet.Tables[0].Rows[0][0] + "]]>";
```

Now I get this ouput:

```
<MyTag>&lt;![CDATA[My html string in &lt;b&gt;BOLD&lt;/b&gt;]]&gt;</MyTag>
```

Almost correct. I've tried escaping the "<" using backslash, but the backslash
is output as a character...

How can I get the output to use the literal "<" and ">" ?

Comment: What is wrong with encoding the the special characters?  See Wiki : https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_XML_and_HTML_character_entity_references

Comment: The XML interpreter in DataSet and XMLDoc treats it as text, not a CDATA tag so the "[" and "CDATA" etc get included as part of the string and this should not happen.